# Updated Arduino IDE and Arduino not working

Tags: arduino-uno

I've had the 1.0.5 IDE on my PC, which worked great. Now I've just decided to update to 1.6.6. After some stupid Java errors and trial and error, I got it to work.

I recompiled my project. Massive errors. Fixed the errors and compiled again.

It stated "Uploading..." That took much longer than before, but I saw the "This takes xxx memory and xxx bytes on the device" yadi yadi ya.

I decided to unplug the Arduino, swap some jumpers and reconnect it (as I've always done). Only this time - I hear 3 beeps from my PC (the sound you hear with broken USB devices). The COM port is no longer recognized.

How do  I fix this? Did that IDE upgrade just brick my Arduino?

Comment: Have you tried switching it off and on again?

Comment: Lol, thanks. I might be on to something here though, hang on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, seems to be fixed. After a 3rd reinstall it seems like its fixed. I reinstalled the whole package, including the drivers, and now it seems to recognize the device again.

Also the compiling now stops properly when done and shows "upload complete".

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question shows as resolved.  In the past we'd probably have just closed the question as "too localized" however that no longer seems to be an option, with the result that the question gets pointlessly churned up now and then.

Comment: Hey, sorry yeah I forgot about doing it. Its not possible to accept as a solution immediately, I had to wait a day or 2, but didn't put it in my calendar :) Thanks for the heads up.